# How to log a QueryDefinition with applied parameters?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

One can create a [QueryDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.querydefinition?view=azure-dotnet) (package: **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos**) in .NET with following C# code

```cs
QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(
    "select * from t where t.Account = @account")
    .WithParameter("@account", 12345);
```

but how do you log the QueryDefinition with applied parameters?

e.g. the query that will be executed in code above would be
`"select * from t where t.Account = 12345"` as string so it could be then written to console with following code

```cs
string queryWithParameters = query // Missing step here
Console.WriteLine(queryWithParameters);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide information like where do you want to log it? Also, what SDK you are using?

Comment: Query you provided above looks like you took that from [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.querydefinition.withparameter?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cosmos-querydefinition-withparameter(system-string-system-object)) document means you are using Azure SDK for .NET ?

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: Where do you want to log the QueryDefinition?

Comment: @Balaji Isn't Console.WriteLine enough?

Answer (score 0):

> How to log a QueryDefinition with applied parameters?

To log the QueryDefinition with applied parameters to the console, you can follow the code below. The parameter `@account` will filter and get the respective data and prints the query in the console using the `Console.WriteLine()` method.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   using (var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, AuthorizationKey))
    {
       var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(DatabaseId);
       var container = database.GetContainer(ContainerId);

       int accountId = 12345;
       QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(
         "select * from t where t.Account = @account")
          .WithParameter("@account", accountId);

        string queryString = query.QueryText.Replace("@account", accountId.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Query with parameters: " + queryString);
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Query with parameters: select * from t where t.Account = 12345
```

Comment: Hi, I am asking for generic solution. So you can input any QueryDefinition that has the parameters already added and then get the final query.